# Problemas al validar rutas en react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy tratando de crear un componente que me sirva para validar rutas la finalidad es pasarle a traves de una propiedad llamada `protect`, el componente al cual quiero validar  y por otras propiedad donde quiero q se redirija en caso de que falle.

El problema esta en cuando intento usar este componente dos o mas veces, solo me funciona para el primero, buscando me di de cuenta que las propiedades para los componente instanciados despues del primero no las esta tomando hay alguna forma de bindear esas propiedades para cada componente en el cual se usen?

```
 class PrivateTwo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.Component = this.props.protect;
    this.customPath = this.props.customPath;
    this.toFailed = this.props.toFailed;
    this.validate = this.props.validate;
  }
  render() {
    let Component = this.Component;

    console.log(this.customPath);
    return (
      <Route
        path={this.customPath}
        render={props => {
          if (this.validate) {
            return <Component {...props} />;
          } else {
            return (
              <Redirect
                to={{
                  pathname: this.toFailed,
                  state: { from: this.props.location }
                }}
              />
            );
          }
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default PrivateTwo;
```

la forma como se usa :

```
<Switch>
   <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
   <PrivateTwo
    customPath="/inner"
    protect={Inner}
    validate={this.props.current} // si es true puedo acceder  a la ruta
    toFailed="/" // ruta a donde redirijo si falla la validacion
    />
   <PrivateTwo
    customPath="/contact"
    protect={Contact}
    validate={this.props.current} // si es true puedo acceder  a la ruta
    toFailed="/"
   />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que el `constructor` es llamado solo cuando el componente es creado, podrías utilizar algún método del [ciclo de vida de un componente](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle), como `componentDidUpdate()`, validar que los `props` sean diferentes y asignar los valores a tus variables.

O podrías utilizar los valores del `props` directamente en la función `render()`

```
class PrivateTwo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {
      protect,
      customPath,
      toFailed,
      validate,
      location 
    } = this.props;
    const MyComponent = protect;

    console.log(MyComponent);
    return (
      <Route
        path={customPath}
        render={props => {
          if (validate) {
            return <MyComponent {...props} />;
          } else {
            return (
              <Redirect
                to={{
                  pathname: toFailed,
                  state: { from: location }
                }}
              />
            );
          }
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: vale muchas gracias